# Watermarking Images with Wordpress with WP_Image_Editor

Tags: images

I really like the `WP_Image_Editor` class. I wanted to use it for some custom functionality I'm making, but I was wondering - Watermarking images - is there a way that I could use the objects created by `WP_Image_Editor` to merge an image with a watermark? I cannot figure out any obvious way.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to use these classes the only way would be to extend both existing implementations `Wp_Image_Editor_Imagick` and `Wp_Image_Editor_GD`.

Here's an approach for the `Wp_Image_Editor_GD`:

```
namespace WPSE98156;

use
    Wp_Image_Editor_Gd,
    Wp_Error;

class WatermarkImageEditor extends Wp_Image_Editor_Gd {

    /*
     * @param resource $stamp (A GD image resource)
     *
     * @return bool|WP_Error
     */
    public function stamp_watermark( $stamp ) {

        /**
         * The resource of the image to edit is stored in
         * $this->image, after $this->load() was called
         */
        $loaded = $this->load();
        if ( is_wp_error( $loaded ) )
            return $loaded;

        // Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
        $marge_right = 10;
        $marge_bottom = 10;
        $sx = imagesx( $stamp );
        $sy = imagesy( $stamp );

        // Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo
        // width to calculate positioning of the stamp.
        imagecopy(
            $this->image,
            $stamp,
            imagesx( $this->image ) - $sx - $marge_right,
            imagesy( $this->image ) - $sy - $marge_bottom,
            0,
            0,
            imagesx( $stamp ),
            imagesy( $stamp )
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param array $args
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function test( $args = [] ) {

        /**
         * Maybe implement your own test here, whether the environment
         * is able to deal with your implementation of the
         * stamp_watermark() method
         */
        return parent::test( $args );
    }

    /**
     * @param string $mime_type
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function supports_mime_type( $mime_type ) {

        /**
         * Todo: Check here if the implementation of the method stamp_watermark()
         * can deal with the mime-types image/png, image/jpeg and image/gif
         */
        return parent::supports_mime_type( $mime_type );
    }
}
```

The implementation follows [this example on php.net](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php).

Now that you have your implementation you must add the new class to the stack of possible image editors using the filter `wp_image_editors`:

```
namespace WPSE98156;

add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', function( $editors ) {

    if ( ! is_array( $editors ) )
        return $editors; //someone broke the filtered value

    array_unshift( $editors, WatermarkImageEditor::class );

    return $editors;
} );
```

Now it's likely possible to get an instance of your custom editor when calling `wp_get_image_editor()`:

```
$editor = wp_get_image_editor( '/path/to/image.jpeg' );
if ( ! is_wp_error( $editor ) && is_callable( [ $editor, 'stamp_watermark' ] ) && ! is_wp_error( $loaded ) ) {

    $stamp = imagecreatefrompng( '/path/to/watermark.png' );
    $success = $editor->stamp_watermark( $stamp );
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $success ) )
        $editor->save();
}
```

You could also simply create the instance explicitly. Every other client, using `wp_get_image_editor()` won't be aware of the method `stamp_watermark()` anyway.

**Some important notes:**

- The code is not tested. It's meant to provide a first approach on how to extend the `Wp_Image_Editor_Gd` class.
- The examples show syntax that requires at least PHP 5.5
- All tasks about loading required files are not shown. Use proper auto loading.
- I'm not into the details of the GD API. So I'm not sure about supported mime-types, you should test this and implement the methods `test()` and `supportet_mime_types()` according to this.

Answer (score 2):

I have had a lot of problems implementing David code. I had errors like “WP_IMAGE_EDITOR_GD” not found, “WatermarkImageEditor” not found…
And when I got it to work, it didn’t work with alpha channel png, so I lost a lot of hours making it work with them. So I will explain how I have it.

Put all this code in a php file, mine is called watermark.php.

```
<?php
class WatermarkImageEditor extends WP_Image_Editor_GD {
    public function stamp_watermark( $stampPath, $marginH=0, $marginV=0 ) {
        $loaded = $this->load();
        if ( is_wp_error( $loaded ) ) return $loaded;

        $stamp=imagecreatefrompng( $stampPath );
        if(is_wp_error($stamp)){ return $stamp; }
        imagealphablending($stamp, true);

        $sx = imagesx( $stamp );
        $sy = imagesy( $stamp );
        imagealphablending($this->image, true);
        imagecopy(
            $this->image, $stamp,$marginH,$this->size['height']-$sy-$marginV,0,0,$sx, $sy
        );  
    }

    public static function test( $args = [] ) { return parent::test( $args ); }

    public static function supports_mime_type( $mime_type ) { return parent::supports_mime_type( $mime_type ); }
}
```

Now, we need to register the filter. I am using it in my own plugin, so I have this code on my main plugin file, but you can also put it on other place like functions.php. Note that I am using require_once to load watermark.php, so watermark.php has to be in the same folder.

```
add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', function( $editors ) {
    require_once __DIR__. '/watermark.php';
    if ( ! is_array( $editors ) )
        return $editors; //someone broke the filtered value
    array_unshift( $editors, "WatermarkImageEditor");
    return $editors;
} );
```

And the last step, call to stamp_watermark(). On this example, I am loading an image from disk, resizing it, putting the watermark, and saving it. Note that stamp_watermark() receives on the first parameter, the path or url of the watermark, the other 2 parameters are the optional margin.

```
$editor= wp_get_image_editor($imagePath);
$editor->resize(1920, 1080, TRUE);
if(is_callable([$editor,'stamp_watermark'])){
  $success = $editor->stamp_watermark( ABSPATH.'wp-content/uploads/watermark-full.png', 20, 20 );       
  if(!is_wp_error($success)){ $editor->save($imagePath); }
}
```